# Hash based stream cipher where the input is a constant, key, nonce and counter

Tags: stream-cipher, sha-256

This is a question out of **curiosity** !

A hash function produces an output that is considered computationally infeasible to reverse.

Let's consider, for the sake of illustration purposes a *tried and tested* hash function like SHA 256, belonging to any of the families ( 2 or 3). Since the block size for SHA 256 is 512 bits or 64 bytes, we could fill it in the following way, inspired by the ChaCha20 stream cipher.

```
cccc cccc cccc cccc kkkk kkkk kkkk kkkk kkkk kkkk kkkk kkkk bbbb nnnn nnnn nnnn
```

`c` - some fixed constants 
`k` - key 
`n` - nonce 
`b` - counter (32 bits)

Each letter strings corresponds to a **byte**.

**NOTE** : The constants could be sacrificed for nonce bytes, hence facilitating a random IV, of bit length >= 128 bits. The counter could also be made to support 64 bits the same way.

We could generate $2^{n} . (blocksize/2)$ bytes of pseudo random key stream, that could be XORed with the plaintext to get ciphertext, where $n$ is the bit length of  the counter, $blocksize$ is the block size (in bytes) of the hash function, used. 
In this case $blocksize$ is 64 for SHA 256...

Let the counter used be $n$ bits. There are $2^{n}$ possible values for the counter. Since output of the hash function   is $blocksize / 2 $ bytes for any individual value of the counter, the scheme can generate a maximum of $2^{n} . (blocksize/2)$ bytes.

Here $n = 32$ so we get, $(2^{32}) . (64/2)$ bytes.

I realize that, giving $x$ bytes of input (where $x$ `= len(constants) + len(key) + len(nonce) + len(counter)` ) and getting $x/2$ bytes as output from the hash function is a kind of inefficiency (SHA - 256), given the fact that the hash function has to run once more (for every input block of size $x$, (additional data of size $x$)) with MD complaint padding information (byte `0x80` followed by $55$ null bytes, and $8$ byte length encoding) . That could cost double CPU clock cycles, for every call to a stream generating function.

In the case of SHA 256 $x = 64$ bytes.

Also, 
This scheme, is extremely inefficient compared to other stream ciphers available like Chacha20 / Salsa20 !

But,

- Is this a good scheme ?
- What are the possible security flaws,    (theoretical/implementation)
  in this protocol?
- If this is secure, can this scheme offer $256$ bit security ?
- What are the possible Quantum attacks on this scheme ?
- Since SHA-256 family of hash functions is immune to side channel attacks, will that be an added advantage?

Every advice and guidance, will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question [SHA256-based stream cipher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15471/18298) or this [Is it feasible to build a stream cipher from a cryptographic hash function?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48/18298) or this [A simple block cipher based on the SHA-256 hash function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1703/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka I saw your links. The essence of their ideas is same, using a hash function to create a stream cipher. This one uses a counter to create pseudo random bytes, keeping the nonce, key, and constants constant for every call. But, the nonce is ephemeral for every encrypted session.

Comment: That is necessary for every stream cipher, too. [What is the significance of IV in stream ciphers like Trivium?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/79887/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka Thankyou for your reply! Here the bit length of nonce can be increased (>=128 bits) to facilitate random nonces by sacrificing the constants !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do this. Officially the output of a hash function is not directly designed for this, but the output of SHA-256 is no doubt randomized enough to be used as a base for a stream cipher. And actually, ChaCha & Salsa [use what is basically the same approach](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51/1172), but with a different PRF (compared with a PRP when a block cipher is used).

Of course, the devil is in the details. The nonce (96 bits) and counter (32 bits) are rather on the short side. Besides that, they don't follow the convention of having the more static nonce first and the counter next. Having a nonce for domain separation is nice, but as the key should be fully randomized, I guess it is not strictly required for this scheme.

As for the applicability: you haven't specified any padding scheme, and you do seem to be using the full 512 bit block size. That means you should have access to the low level block-based SHA-256 functionality to implement the scheme. *Otherwise* you would have **two** full blocks of SHA-256 to perform for one 256 bit output and one block with the padding and length encoding. The output is then the output of the last block operation (which also depends on the first one as the state is maintained). So in that case you would have a 4 x drawback compared with using a normal stream cipher at the minimum when using the full SHA-256.

If you are using the block size then you could define separate SHA-256 constants for the starting state instead of trying to shoe-horn them into the input block.

Generally the hash functions don't use table lookups and should be relatively safe against side channel attacks. Of course, side channel attacks are implementation dependent, so this detail is not a final verdict for any system.

---

A minor note: although logical, the output is **not** entirely related to the input block size for generic hash functions. So specifying $n / 2$ as output size feels a bit strange to me.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer! I was referring to SHA 256, therefore we have $n/2$ where $n$ is 64 bytes. Can a Quantum computer compromise this?

Comment: It may bring back the complexity to $2^{128}$ using Grovers algorithm (in the worst case). Otherwise, currently, we don't think so.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I think Vivekanand uses block size as the 512-bit block size of SHA256 and 256 as the output size as an unusual notation. That means it can be used without padding.

Comment: @kelalaka It is also specific to collision search, right? And basically we're dealing with a keyed hash construction here, even though it **uses** a collision resistant hash function to implement it. I haven't studied Brazards attack, but is it applicable?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes, I've forgotten the key.

Comment: That's OK, just relying on Grover being the maximum that can be achieved is also a bit dangerous, I must admit. I'd rather have that criticized than not :)